# Return True False On SQL When Evaluating Repeated Rows

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that only returns either true or false when the following happens:

I have a table called `GAS_cards`

```
idCard INT PK
idCardType INT
```

I specify various idCards (so far I have this)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GAS_cards_spEvaluateCards_many] 
    @cardString VARCHAR(100)
AS 

SELECT * 
FROM GAS_cards 
WHERE (@cardString = '-1' OR ',' + @cardString + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, idCard) + ',%')
```

What I want to do here is the following evaluation. 
Let's say that the query returns 10 rows. Everything depends on the `idCardType`. If at least one value equals 3, the rest also have to be 3; else it should return a false.

Comment: Could you provide some sample inputs of @cardString?'

Comment: '1,2,3,6,10,11,12,13,14,23'

Comment: And those are idCard values, right?

Comment: that's correct... those are the cards that I want to evaluate....
each one will have an idCardType...
could be either 1, 2 or 3...
if either none or all equal 3... returns true..
if there's at least one 3 and another value.... returns false

Comment: What db is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go. I dont have a SQL instance available to test, but for the most part I think it will do the trick. Basically I take the idCard string value and then add that into dynamic sql to create a table of ids.  Then I compare the number of rows in the table to the number of rows that have the value 3.  If they equal then I select 1 otherwise do 0.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GAS_cards_spEvaluateCards_many] 
    @cardString VARCHAR(100)
AS 

--Temporary table for our cards
CREATE TABLE #Cards
(
 idCard int,
 idCardType int 
)

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max);

SET @Sql = 'INSERT INTO #Cards 
SELECT idCard, idCardType FROM GAS_cards
WHERE idCard in (' + @cardString + ')';

IF EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM #Cards c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Cards c2
   ON c1.idCard = c2.idCard
   AND c2.idCardType = 3 -- Your card type
WHERE
   c2.idCard IS NULL)
  SELECT 0
ELSE
  SELECT 1
```

I think you might be able to use

```
SET @TotalRows = @@rowcount
```

But I'm not too sure if the scope of the dynamic sql wouldn't let you see the count.  Also if you're bringing across a string like you say, I don't see how to do this without dynamic sql. Also an out parameter on the procedure might be good as well.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is ok in accepted answer, but for performance reasons better to use RETURN statement if this this single result.
Example we have `sp_checkexist`:

```
IF EXISTS(...) 
RETURN 0 
ELSE 
RETURN 1
```

and in other places we check TRUE or FALSE condition in such way:

```
IF ( sp_checkexist(@variable)=1 ) 
... statement if TRUE
else
... statement if FALSE
```